# "comes" or "comes around" once in every four years

Tags: difference

> My birthday **comes** once in every four years

or

> My birthday **comes around** once in every four years

Should I use *around* or not?

Comment: I would leave out *in*.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct indirectly as they both successfully communicate that your birthday occurs once every four years.

The most appropriate on the other hand would have to be the first sentence

> "My birthday comes once in every four years"

as it is more direct and doesn't use the word around to add an unnecessary emphasis on the time taken for your birthday to come.

I'd personally look at the sort of emphasis you want the words to make. Is it just normal that someone's birthday is coming once in four years or do you wish to make it seem as special as it is.